# implement iAd video with MPMoviePlayerController with playPrerollAdWithCompletionHandler method

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ios7, iad

Well, I want to show a video ad just before starting a video in MPMoviePlayer

This is what I am doing:-

```
    moviePlayer = [MPMoviePlayerController new];

    moviePlayer.contentURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://xyz/xyz.m3u8"];

    [moviePlayer playPrerollAdWithCompletionHandler:^(NSError *error) {
            // Check if error is non-nil during development
            [moviePlayer play];
        }];
    moviePlayer.view.frame=CGRectMake(0, 20, 300, self.view.frame.size.width);
    [self.view addSubview:moviePlayer.view];
    [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
```

And in Appdelegate.m

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    [MPMoviePlayerController preparePrerollAds];
    return YES;
}
```

**But what more should I do to show an ad video or how to configure the iAD to let the app understand which specific video to play as ad.**

Currently the app is just playing this url "http://xyz/xyz.m3u8" video but not showing any ad.

Answer (score 0):

You need to `prepareToPlay` your `MPMoviePlayerController` before calling `playPrerollAdWithCompletionHandler` and add your `MPMoviePlayerController` to your `view` before you `play` it. Also, you may be playing the video before `[MPMoviePlayerController preparePrerollAds]` has a chance to download the video ad completely. Check my example:

```
#import "ViewController.h"
@import iAd;
@import MediaPlayer;

@interface ViewController () {
    MPMoviePlayerController *moviePlayer;
}

@end

@implementation ViewController

-(void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Preload ad
    [MPMoviePlayerController preparePrerollAds];

    // Create our MPMoviePlayerController
    moviePlayer =[[MPMoviePlayerController alloc]init];
    [moviePlayer.view setFrame: self.view.bounds];
    [moviePlayer setFullscreen:YES animated:YES];
}

-(IBAction)playButton:(id)sender {
    // Add MPMoviePlayerController to our view
    [self.view addSubview:moviePlayer.view];

    // Path of movie you want to play
    NSString *moviePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"someVideo" ofType:@"MOV"];

    // Set the contents of our MPMoviePlayerController to our path
    [moviePlayer setContentURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:moviePath]];

    // Prepare our movie for playback
    [moviePlayer prepareToPlay];

    // Play our movie with a prerolled ad
    [moviePlayer playPrerollAdWithCompletionHandler:^(NSError *error) {
        [moviePlayer play];
    }];
}
```